# Speed of sprite on canvas different on different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am using the formula to calculate speed and am using the screen width as distance and fps as time. The speed of the sprite is still different when moving across the screen. How should I change the formula in order to make the speed feel the same on all screen sizes?

```
public static float distanceX = Screen.width;
public static float time = 60f ;
public static float speed = Player.distanceX / Player.time;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, you have to define what the "feel" needs to be.  For example, suppose the device is held in landscape orientation.  A 4:3 device is much narrower than a 16:9 device, so if you have a bunch of squares arranged horizontally on the screen, you'll have more of them on the 16:9 device than on the 4:3 device.

If your goal is to move from one side of the screen to the other in a constant amount of time, then the formula you show in your question is correct.

If your goal is to move past N squares in a constant amount of time, then you need a different formula.  It sounds like this is what you want.

One approach is to define a device-independent "arena" in which everything moves, and then fit it to the device.  For example, you could define the world to be 1000x1000, and that things move at 100 units per second.  You then fit the arena to the screen by either cutting off the top and bottom, or letter-boxing the sides.  A side-scrolling platformer would usually match the arena to the device height, and then show a wider or narrower field of view horizontally.  (For an example of this approach, see [Android Breakout](https://github.com/fadden/android-breakout/blob/master/src/com/faddensoft/breakout/GameState.java#L55).)

On a related note, it's unwise to assume that a device has a certain fixed frame rate.  Some advice can be found in [this appendix](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops).

Comment: I will try making a world to set to the screen. Thanks!